# How to save data or value on textbox to SQL Server for selected table

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, textbox

This is the data pass from form 1 when the from3 button click:

```
string DataT1, Table2, T3;
DataTable DT5,DT;

public Form3(DataTable DT4,string DT1, string T2,string T31)
{
            DataT1 = DT1;
            Table2 = T2;
            T3 = T31;
            DT5 = DT4;
            InitializeComponent();
            loaddata();
}
```

The textbox fill automatically when the datagridview is fill with data

```
 private void FillData(DataTable DataT)
    {
        TextBox TB1;
        int y = 12;
        foreach (DataColumn DC in DataT.Columns)
        {
            TB1 = TB(0, y);
            TB1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text".ToString(), DataT, DC.ColumnName));
            panel1.Controls.Add(TB1);
            y += 23;
        }
    }

        //the textbox object
        private TextBox TB(int x,int y)
        {
            TextBox TB1 = new TextBox 
            { 
                Text = "",
                Size = new Size(150,50),
                Location=new Point(x,y)
            };
            return TB1;
        }
```

Below is the code that I want to add the textbox data or value to SQL Server when the button save is clicked:

```
private void loaddata()
    {
        DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection SC = new SqlConnection(DataT1);
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(Table2, SC);
        SqlCommandBuilder SCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);
        SDA.Fill(DT1);
        DT = DT1;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
        //the code to save and update data on textbox
        FillData((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int j = 0;
        string[] Text = null;
        foreach (TextBox TB in panel1.Controls)
        {
            j++;
            Text[j].Insert(j, TB.Text.ToString());//this way i create a string[] to save each textbox value
        }
        /*how the code to save programmatically added textbox value to sql
         * database follow by each textbox to each columns in database 
         * table and another sql command to insert new record*/
    }
```

This is the form1 SQL Server connection string

```
//this is the form one, the database and table is choose by combobox and fill it to datagridview
        string T1, T2, T3;
        DataTable Data2;

        private void LoadData()
        {
            T1 = "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
            T2 = "Select * from " + comboBox3.SelectedItem;
            T3 = comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
            SqlConnection SCConnect = new SqlConnection(T1);
            SCConnect.Open();
            StringBuilder SBBuilder = new StringBuilder(T2);
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SBBuilder.ToString(),SCConnect);
            SqlCommandBuilder SCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(DT);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
            Data2 = DT;
            filltexttotextbox((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
        }
```

When the button click it will open and pass data to form3:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 F3 = new Form3(Data2, T1, T2,T3);
            F3.ShowDialog();
        }
```

> to add new record to database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xyTa.jpg)

> to update record to database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR2R0.jpg)

Comment: You mean you want to save all textbox value in textbox column to SQL server? Each textbox would have their own record?

Comment: @TấnNguyên No, because after the form load, datagridview will auto fill with data and the textbox will programmatically add on panel1, the code that i want is after the textbox load and fill in panel1, when i key in something on textbox and click the button it will save the text or value on textbox to sql database by insert new row or update on table.

Comment: @1878alianwere I know, but what if you changed text on multiple textboxes, then button save is clicked, what are you desired here? Save all changes? My point here that you should implement one more button column, and if it's clicked, trigger the event and upsert on your database. All solves

Comment: @TấnNguyên now i can get the value on textbox already, but in sql command how i update the data that i changes on each textbox to save in sql database, because when the button is click, it will save the changes that i make on textbox to sql server. and how the sql command for insert new record to database table column follow by each textbox to each columns?TQ

Comment: To trigger the changes of each row, you have 3 options: TextChanged event would be fired on each letter inserted or removed, so it's bad. Leave event will be fired when the pointer leave focus, it's seem good. Third, implement a button column that will fire event when button is clicked. Last 2 options are good because could insert new record row by row and no need `button1_Click`

Comment: if you would like to use `button1_Click`, I recommend you create a Dictionary that store all changes fired by 2 last options I suggested. Then it will insert SQL as a bundle

Comment: @Tấn Nguyên have any coding on how to use it. TQ

Comment: I posted my code. Hope it helps

Comment: @TấnNguyên i just now edit my question with the picture together.

Comment: yes, my technical that use Origin and Editot table might work in your case. My suggestion is going edit it in datagridview and no need to pass the data to panel1

Comment: After listing out the changes, you could call sql update with many row changes at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to handle the changes that don't to fire the changes event basically.
Just save the loaded as OriginDataTable and use EditorDataTable as a editor.

For quickly implementation. I will use DataGridView as a editor directly without passing to panel1 on your code.

```
    DataTable OriginalDataTable = new DataTable();
    DataTable EditorDataTable = new DataTable();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EditorDataTable.Columns.Add("Col1");
        EditorDataTable.Columns.Add("Col2");
        EditorDataTable.Columns.Add("Col3");

        EditorDataTable.Rows.Add("my-col-1-row-1", "my-col-2-row-1", "my-col-3-row-1");
        EditorDataTable.Rows.Add("my-col-1-row-2", "my-col-2-row-2", "my-col-3-row-2");
        EditorDataTable.Rows.Add("my-col-1-row-3", "my-col-2-row-3", "my-col-3-row-3");

        dataGridView.DataSource = EditorDataTable;
        OriginalDataTable = EditorDataTable.Copy(); // Save loaded datatable
    }
```

Then I would use the comparison between origin and editor

```
    private IEnumerable<DataRow> ListOutDataRowChanged(DataTable originDt, DataTable changeDt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < originDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (string.Join(";",originDt.Rows[i].ItemArray) != string.Join(";", changeDt.Rows[i].ItemArray))
                yield return originDt.Rows[i];
        }
    }
```

The save button would be

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = ListOutDataRowChanged(OriginalDataTable, EditorDataTable);
        MessageBox.Show("List changes count: " + list.Count());
        // Insert this list to SQL here
    }
```

The benefit of this implementation is:

- We could handle when we are gonna send to SQL
- Edited then restore back wouldn't count as changes
- No need to trigger fire event

[image]
[image]

Rollback

[image]